# ASP.NET MVC 3 custom attribute with Ninject not executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, filterattribute

I must be doing something wrong because I have replicated many answers on this subject.  My attribute binding is not being hit and I'm not sure why.

Controller.cs

```
[NatGeoUserAccessAuthorization]
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult Teacher(string id)
        {
```

Attribute/Fitler

```
public class NatGeoUserAccessAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute{}
    public class NatGeoUserAccessAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter 
    {
        private readonly IUsersService _usersService;

        public NatGeoUserAccessAuthorizationFilter(IUsersService usersService)
        {
            _usersService = usersService;
        }

        public string QueryStringName { get; set; }

        #region Implementation of IAuthorizationFilter

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!_usersService.HasUserAccess(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[QueryStringName ?? "id"]))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "AccessDenied" }, { "controller", "Error" } });
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {            
            // NLog Custom Layouts
            ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition("utc_date", typeof(UtcDateRenderer));
            ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition("web_variables", typeof(WebVariablesRenderer));

            // Setup IoC Container
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(Bootstrap.Configure((kernel) =>
            {
                kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory<MySqlConnection>>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", Config.Data.MySQLConnection);

                ManagerBindings.Register(kernel);
                ProviderBindings.Register(kernel);
                RepositoryBindings.Register(kernel);
                ServiceBindings.Register(kernel);
                ValidationBindings.Register(kernel);

                kernel.BindFilter<NatGeoUserAccessAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0).WhenActionMethodHas<NatGeoUserAccessAuthorizationAttribute>();

                kernel.Bind<IUserProfile>().To<UserProfile>();
                kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
            }));

            // Custom Default Model Binder
            ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new ValidationModelBinder();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Bootstrap.cs

```
public class Bootstrap
    {
        public delegate void IocRegistrationDelegate(IKernel kernel);

        public static IDependencyResolver Configure(IocRegistrationDelegate serviceBindings)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            serviceBindings.Invoke(kernel);

            return new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't bind IUsersService with ninject I guess? Try this: kernel.Bind<IUsersService >().To<UsersService >(); And specifier a [AttributeUsage] on your attribute class

Comment: I did but it is under ServiceBindings.Register(kernel);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an own bootstrapping mechanism that doesn't support filter bindings. Read the docu how to use the one that comes with Ninject.Mvc3 on http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki

Comment: That is probably it.  I have used NinjectHttpApplication before, and had an issue with it which now I can't remember on another project.  I will try to use this setup again on this current project.